# How can I fix the look of child 1 under a dropdown navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, frontend

How can I fix the look of child 1 under `dropdown` NavBar? Also, how easy is it to change this into a flexbox, and make a button to make the code less cluttered via JavaScript?

I want the `#dropDown` as the parent navbar item and `#child` as the child of that navbar item. without a large white space bar (please run the code in full screen to see)

Also, I would like the bar to be visible on mobile. Some elements show up, but the Contact does not show up.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

a {
  color: #000;
}


/* header */

.header {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header li a:hover,
.header .menu-btn:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.header .logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* menu */

.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}


/* menu icon */

.header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
}


/* menu btn */

.header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu {
  max-height: 240px;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}


/* 48em = 768px */

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .header li {
    float: left;
  }
  .header li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <a href="" class="logo">CSS Nav</a>
    <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
    <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#work">Our Work</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#dropDown">dropDown</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#child">child 1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#careers">Careers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: In your current HTML structure there is no relationship between `#dropDown` and `#child`.

Comment: It's used in the following CSS. I may not need it if i can replace the css script with a js

Comment: @MI thought having a  <ul> under a <li> would work . but it doesn't .

Comment: First try using Javascript yourself and then if you can't do it come here showing what you have tried. The `#child` is  after `a href="#dropDown"` in the HTML structure but there is no direct relationship between them. They are not siblings nor parent->child. As you can see `#child` is inside a `li` inside an `ul` and that UL is the SIBLING ( not child ) of `a` . You could select the child with `a + ul li a`

Comment: @MihaiT I wanted to make it look right with CSS before trying the js.

Comment: @MihaiT I am so new to CSS and HTML and i was stuck for a long time on this code and that's why I posted here, I tried to follow what you said but I can not get the output I need. would be helpful if you can show it on the code.Thanks